# How do i get a audio file URL from the iPhone to my App to use that audio

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.2, media-player

I need to access the iPhone music libary to get a song that i can use in the app. How can this be done? Any useful advice of what framework to use or a tutorial that could help?

Plus i need it to be able to work with AVAudioPlayer. I need the app to return a URL of the song in the Phone to the player Function. (Need Function in AVAudioPlayer to do audio Visualizer)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the apple documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AddMusic/Introduction/Intro.html)

Comment: the link above does not retrieve any form of URL from the media player and the Visualizer they made is just in Random function what i need is a Visualizer that plays according to the mood of the music..